# SPARK - assign multiple cores to one task in RDD.map in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, parallel-processing, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I am new to SPARK and I'm trying to use RDD.map in pyspark to parallelize running of a method named *function* in the SPARK framework (72 cores in total in an Standalone SPARK cluster - one driver with 100G RAM and 3 workers each with 24 cores and 100G RAM).

My goal is to run *function* for 200 times and average over the results. The output of the *function* is an numpy.array of size 12 by num_of_samples (which is a huge variable in terms of memory).

My first attempt was to create an RDD of size 200, then use RDD.map and reduce at the end:

```
sum_data = sc.parallelize(range(0,200)).map(function).reduce(lambda x,y:x+y)
```

Despite the fact that I set the spark driver-memory to maximum, it runs out of memory at the reduce level (I guess due to the huge numpy.array output of the *function*). I figured the maximum number of element that I can put into my RDD in order to avoid memory error is something about 40 elements:

```
sum_data = sc.parallelize(range(0,40)).map(function).reduce(lambda x,y:x+y)
```

Now when I try this, I see that SPARK creates 40 tasks and assign exactly one core to each of them (using only 40 cores out of 72 available cores in the cluster). So the other 32 cores are idle and not being used, resulting in a very slower run-time. I was wondering if this approach is correct and how can I make RDD.map to consume all the available cores instead on using one core for each mapping?

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be achieved by specifying the number of partitions that spark have to divide your `RDD`s into. 
the simplest way for doing this is to add the optional `numSlices` parameter in the `parallelize` method call, this will ensure that spark split your data into  `numSlices` partitions and I think it will be using the whole cores.

Please refer to the [official documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.SparkContext) for more information.

Comment: I tried that already, it didn't work:
sc.parallelize(range(0,40),72)

I guess when the number of elements in the RDD is less than number of partitions (numSlices), it doesn't work.